# Laravel 9, passing a string as name class in function declaration argument type

Tags: php, function, laravel-9

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ExampleFormRequest;

class GenericController extends Controller{

    public $requestClassName = "ExampleFormRequest";

    public function store( $requestClassName $request )
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Is there any way to pass a string as a declaration argument type?

Comment: Never tried and doesn't look like a good practice(even if made possible some day). How many types of `$requestClassName` can exist?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ExampleFormRequest;

class GenericController extends Controller{

    public $requestClassName = "ExampleFormRequest";

    public function store( Request $request )
    {
        //do something
        return $this->requestClassName;
    }

}
```